# Multiline and HTML output with YAML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, internationalization, yaml

I am implementing i18n in Ruby and need to make multiline text with html tags for confirmation email (Devise).

My YAML looks like the following:

```
emails:
  reset_html: |
    <p>something goes here</p>
    <p>and here as new line</p>
```

Then in my reset_password_instructions.rb I have:

```
= t('emails.reset_html')
```

Output: "Reset"

If I do it as plain text (no "html" suffix) - it prints the entire text but as one line.

It seems to be implemented as described in YAML for Ruby specification.

Any ideas why it does not work and how to fix it?
Maybe better idea how to make multi-language email templates for standard messages like confirmation and pass reset?

thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to put HTML in your I18n YML files. Perhaps it's better to create an email view along the lines of:

devise/mailer/reset_password.haml

```
%p
  t('emails.reset.dear') #{@resource.name},

%p
  t('emails.reset.reset_requested')

%p 
  = link_to t('emails.reset.change_password'), "http://..."
```

en.yml

```
  en:
    emails:
      reset:
        dear: Dear
        reset_requested: You have requested a ...
        change_password: Change password here
```

(note that I've added the language prefix)

Comment: makes sense, I'll most likely go with this approach. but, do you have an idea why my code does not work?

Comment: _I tried adding inline code here, but that won't work, see my updated answer_